# Accessing drawRect from ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIView subclass with a drawRect method. My viewController uses this subclass (I just set it in the xib), and so UIView draws a rectangle to the screen fine.

Now, I'd like to send a bunch CGRects stored in my viewController to my UIView drawRect method.

I'm unsure how to pass them. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can add properties to your `UIView` subclass to store the `CGRect`'s, set them from your `UIViewController` then call `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` from your `UIViewController`.

Comment: Hi, how exactly would I access the UIView subclass? I don't instantiate it anywhere in the viewController.

Comment: You can access a view controller's view with `self.view`

Comment: Hi there, I get an error: "receiver type 'UIView' for instance message does not declare a method with selector...". I guess that means my viewController is somehow not using the right subclass, although I set it in the xib. How can I set it programmatically? Or other options? Thanks

Comment: OK, I think I got it. I removed the initWithXib. I'm going to create the subclass programmatically and set self.view = subclass. Thanks